# Extra Carriage Returns in Windows 10 - Update Issue?

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, atom-editor, carriage-return

This seems to me like a Windows update issue, but I cannot be sure.

I've started seeing extra carriage returns within text-format documents between lines. Opening these files on older machines works fine and will look like the below:

[image: Original Image]

When I transfer this same file over to my current PC, and open it (not only Notepad, but I've tried many other editors, Notepad++, Atom etc), it is like below:

[image: Current PC Image]

When looking at this within a Hex editor, I cannot see extra carriage returns.

Originally I thought this was an issue with my PC alone, but others within our office are starting to be effected by this. I'm wondering if anyone has seen this and if there's an easy fix?

Thanks for any advice in advance!

Comment: Are they CR-LF or just the LF (or CR) in the hex view? Windows apps usually ignore just CR or LF alone, but perhaps that changed, or the settings for the text editors changed.

Comment: How are you transferring the documents between PCs?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - I have edited "although if I save this and then check, it does add them in on-save" out as I was mistaken. Within the Hex editor it's CR-LF (0D 0A in the one checked). When moving between PC's it doesn't show this anywhere else, no settings have changed within text editors, I have seen this on a fresh install now.

Comment: @Anaksunaman - Either copy + pasting, or moving via USB, I have tried multiple options and it seems like it's doing the same however I move them.